# VBA how to find a particular column name from base workbook into another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

What i am tryin to do is Copy Data from another workbook into this workbook based on column header names, columns are not in the same sequece and not all columns headers are present on whiuch i hv used on error resume next

i used find function to do it, is there ant other way i can do it.

how can i replace find what in "" with a dynamic range or cell reference
here i is the column from base file which i wanty to find in dump wb
Below is my conding

```
For i = 1 To 50


    Windows("Base.xlsm").Activate

    Columns(Columns(i).Address).Select 'i is column number 

    ActiveSheet.Cells(8, i).Select ' this is required column hader to find

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.copy

    Windows("Dump.xlsx").Activate
    Rows("2:2").Select

    Selection.Find(What:="items", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 800000, ActiveCell.Column)).Select


    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.copy
    Windows("Base.xlsm").Activate

    Range("A9").Select 'how to select active cell in the workbook where i want to paste data.
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Next i
```

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question?  (Also, see "[mcve]" as well as "[ask]")

Answer (score 0):

I understand about 10% of your question. but I'll answer:

> how can i replace find what in "" with a dynamic range

you can replace `Find(What:="items")` with a value of a range, e.g. `Find(What:=Range("A1").Value)`, leaving you with this:

```
Selection.Find(What:=Range("A1").Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Comment: what if i want to select a range of cells from a different workbook that is my headers columns and after searching one column header move to another column

Comment: again: I understand about 10% of what you're asking. if you want to open other workbooks you go with "Workbooks.Open(Path, UpdateLinks, ReadOnly)". please open new questions with specific problems - this is too broad